# Incrementing fieldset IDs sometimes results in duplicates

Tags: javascript, fieldset

I am trying to allow the number of input fields to be increased or decreased for several different sections. As demonstrated by the code below, with only 2 sections, each fieldset created should have a unique ID to allow it to be deleted.

I have observed that the IDs are not always unique but it is not consistent. Sometimes I can add 10 fieldsets between the 2 groups and not get any duplicate IDs and other times I will start getting duplicates on the 2nd or 3rd fieldset addition.

As shown in the image below in this particular case the duplicate IDs started happening when the 3rd fieldset was added.

[image: Duplicate ID example from Web Developer inspector]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Testing Fieldset Add/Delete</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function AddGroup1() {

      newFS = newFieldset(); // build a new fieldset ID to use
      infield = '<fieldset id="' + newFS + '"><label for="group1new">Group 1</label>';
      infield += '<input type="text" name="group1[]" value="0" size="15" maxlength="15" />';
      infield += '<a href="#" onclick="deleteID(' + newFS + ');return false;" title="Delete This Entry">';
      infield += 'Delete</a></fieldset>';

      var div = document.getElementById('moregroup1');
      div.innerHTML += infield;

    } // end of the AddGroup1 function

    function AddGroup2() {

      newFS = newFieldset(); // build a new fieldset ID to use
      infield = '<fieldset id="' + newFS + '"><label for="group2new">Group 2</label>';
      infield += '<input type="text" name="group2[]" value="0" size="15" maxlength="15" />';
      infield += '<a href="#" onclick="deleteID(' + newFS + ');return false;" title="Delete This Entry">';
      infield += 'Delete</a></fieldset>';

      var div = document.getElementById('moregroup2');
      div.innerHTML += infield;

    } // end of the AddGroup2 function

    function newFieldset() {

      var fpoint = 1; // fieldset ID pointer so we may address each one individually
      var ids = $("fieldset[id^='newFieldset_']").map(function() { // get any already there
        var partsArray = this.id.toString().split('_'); // break into pieces
        fpoint = partsArray[1]; // first element of the resulting array should be a number
        fpoint++; // increment by one

      }).get(); // end of the map
      return "newFieldset_" + fpoint; // give the caller the new fieldset ID

    } // end of the newFieldset function

    function deleteID(id2Delete) {

      var deleteID = document.getElementById(id2Delete.id);
      deleteID = deleteID.id;
      $("#" + deleteID).remove();

    } // end of the deleteID function
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Testing Fieldset Add/Delete</h1>
  <form method="post" action="WeedsTest.html">

    <fieldset>
      <label for="group1">Group 1</label>
      <input type="text" name="group1[]" value="0" size="15" maxlength="15" />
      <a href="#" onclick="AddGroup1();return false;" title="Add Additional Group 1">Add</a>
    </fieldset>

    <div id="moregroup1"></div>

    <fieldset>
      <label for="group2">Group 2</label>
      <input type="text" name="group2[]" value="0" size="15" maxlength="15" />
      <a href="#" onclick="AddGroup2();return false;" title="Add Additional Group 2">Add</a>
    </fieldset>

    <div id="moregroup2"></div>

  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What are the ids for, is it so that the delete buttons work?  I would use the delete button's relative position in the fieldset to locate the fieldset element and skip the ids altogether.

Comment: Yes, the IDs are for the delete button. Not sure what you are suggesting with the 2nd sentence. Each fieldset, other than the first, has a delete option. I was not able to find a way to relate the delete button to a specific fieldset without that ID.

Comment: You should try and make use of jQuery as you can shorten your code in few places. For example, you can use [.clone](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) for duplicating elements. And leverage [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/#event-propagation) for dynamically-created elements.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Mikey but I was not able to get .clone to work as expected. The contents of the first fieldset, which would be what is cloned, contains the Add button but the cloned sets would need a Delete button instead. If there is a way to use .clone and change specific parts of the fieldset contents I'm all ears. jQuery and JavaScript are not my strong suits.

Comment: I hear you. It does take practice to get used to the JavaScript world. When you clone the element, cache it (store it in a variable). Then find the button within that element and remove it -- or better [replace it](https://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) e.g. `clonedFieldset.find('a').replaceWith(...)`.

Comment: Thanks again. Will have to give that another go.

Comment: I have to give another shout-out to James and Mikey. My resulting JS file is 88 lines smaller AND I no longer have to make an AJAX call when additional fieldsets are added which makes things all that more responsive. You guys made my day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick change to use relative positioning to locate the fieldset to remove.  Your delete buttons change to:

```
<a href="#" onclick="deleteID(this);return false"......
```

And your deleteID function becomes

```
function deleteID(button) {

  var fieldset = $(button).parent();
  $(fieldset).remove();

}
```

Comment: Thank you James. That solves the problem and removes the need for trying to calculate unique IDs which is much cleaner. In the real code there is also an AJAX call involved so every little bit to speed things up really helps.

Comment: Hey Dave - yep relative positioning is very useful in situations like this where you are adding basically the same html as a unit over and over.  There are more tricks to learn, if your html gets more complicated and you can't figure out how the relative part works take a look at jQuery's [`closest`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/).  Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks James. I actually started this exercise trying to use closest but was not able to get it working (probably due to my lack of experience with jQuery). Between clone and closest I'll see how compact I can get this :)

Comment: Just had to drop in again and say thank you to both James and Mikey. Your "push" resulted in a very simple solution using jQuery. What was 9 lines of JS plus a separate function is now a very clean 4 lines of jQuery that is a lot easier to read.