# Set value of cloned fieldset input field

Tags: jquery

This is a follow on question to the question I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44264086/incrementing-fieldset-ids-sometimes-results-in-duplicates). Everything is working as desired except the setting of the value for the 2nd input field, named ***misc_value***, in the example below.

The desire is to have the first input field ***group1*** be blank so the placeholder is shown and have the second input field contain a default value of 0.

If I examine the elements of the cloned fieldset I do see that value="0" is shown for the 2nd input field but nothing is actually displayed and that value is NOT returned on form submission.

I have tried a number of variations on the `$('input[name="misc_value"]').val("0");` line in the example but the result has always been the same.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Testing Input Value</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function AddGroup1() {

 newFS = $('#fsgroup1').clone(true).removeProp("id");
 newFS.find('a').replaceWith('<a href="#" onclick="deleteID(this);return false;" title="Delete This Entry">Delete</a>');
 newFS.find("input:text").val("").end()
 $('input[name="misc_value"]').val("0");
 $("#moregroup1").append(newFS);

}  // end of the AddGroup1 function

function deleteID(button) {

 var fieldset = $(button).parent();
 $(fieldset).remove();

}  // end of the deleteID function
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Testing Input Value</h1>
<form method="post" action="WeedsTest.html">

<fieldset id="fsgroup1">
<label for="group1">Group 1</label>
<input placeholder="Enter misc description" type="text" name="group1[]" value="" size="255" maxlength="255" />

<label for="misc_value">$ Amount</label>
<input type="text" name="misc_value[]" size="15" maxlength="15" value="0" />
<a href="#" onclick="AddGroup1();return false;" title="Add Additional Entry">Add</a>
</fieldset>

<div id="moregroup1"></div>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The desire was a cloned set of the original fields with their default values regardless of whether or not anything had been entered in the original fields. The answer provided below has resolved the problem. Was almost staring me in the face but I couldn't quite see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problems were:

1. No `var` next to `newFS` inside `AddGroup1()`
2. You weren't using `newFS` as the parent element to find `misc_value`
3. Your names for `misc_value` and `group1` were `misc_value[]` and `group1[]`, respectively, in your HTML, so `find` was not working correctly.

See the working example below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Testing Input Value</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function AddGroup1() {

 var newFS = $('#fsgroup1').clone(true).removeProp("id");
 newFS.find('a').replaceWith('<a href="#" onclick="deleteID(this);return false;" title="Delete This Entry">Delete</a>');
 newFS.find("input:text").val("").end()
 newFS.find('input[name="misc_value"]').val("0");
 $("#moregroup1").append(newFS);

}  // end of the AddGroup1 function

function deleteID(button) {

 var fieldset = $(button).parent();
 $(fieldset).remove();

}  // end of the deleteID function
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Testing Input Value</h1>
<form method="post" action="WeedsTest.html">

<fieldset id="fsgroup1">
<label for="group1">Group 1</label>
<input placeholder="Enter misc description" type="text" name="group1" value="" size="255" maxlength="255" />

<label for="misc_value">$ Amount</label>
<input type="text" name="misc_value" size="15" maxlength="15" value="0" />
<a href="#" onclick="AddGroup1();return false;" title="Add Additional Entry">Add</a>
</fieldset>

<div id="moregroup1"></div>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. The use of var did not make any difference though I have added it to be "more correct". Added the cloned element name to the find for misc_value AND adding the [] after it allowed things to work as desired.

Comment: Thanks for that caramba .... the removeProp resulted in the id being undefined, which was fine from my perspective, but your suggestion removes it completely which I like even more.